# How can I write a newline in a string in ColdFusion?

Tags: syntax, coldfusion, newline

Currently I'm putting newlines in strings through one of these two methods:

```
<cfset someStr="This is line 1" & Chr(10) & "This is line 2" & Chr(10) & "This is line 3" />
```

OR

```
<cfset NL=Chr(10) />
<cfset someStr="This is line 1#NL#This is line 2#NL#This is line 3" />
```

Is there anything more like the Java/C++ way?  Something more like this I mean:

```
<cfset someStr="This is line 1\nThis is line 2\nThis is line 3" />
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Your way is correct.  There is no support for \n or \r in CF.  From the [Live Docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_c-d_04.html#4749523)

> - Chr(10) returns a linefeed character
> - Chr(13) returns a carriage return character
> - The two-character string Chr(13) & Chr(10) returns a Windows newline

Comment: Just note that Chr(13) & Chr(10) doesnt work in a simple <cfoutput>. You need to have it in javascript or something else in order to get the newlines to show. I've been discovering this the fun way.

Comment: It works fine in a cfoutput for me.  Of course it won't create a break in html because html treats it as just another whitespace but if you do a view source you would see the break.  Maybe you just need a <br> ?

Comment: Possibly. I just wanted to report that if people are having trouble with it, like I was, they should try putting it in javascript or something to see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 23):

If you are into platform-independent development, you can do:

```
<cfset NL = CreateObject("java", "java.lang.System").getProperty("line.separator")>
```

For example, in your `application.cfm/cfc` or somewhere else high-level and use that.

Comment: that's pretty cool.  i'm new to CF, so i haven't really tapped the potential of the underlying java code yet...

Comment: I use this exclusively, its easy to say "we will only ever run on Windows", but it's going to be a sad day when you have to change hundreds of lines of code scattered about because you were lazy.

Answer (score 12):

i use this:

```
<cfset br = "#chr(13)##chr(10)#">
<cfset someStr="This is line 1#br#This is line 2#br#This is line 3" />
```

Comment: Marc, let's do without the quotes and #'s-
    <cfset br = chr(13) & chr(10) />

Comment: you'll rip quotes and pound signs out of my cold, dead hands Nathan!

Answer (score 5):

Not directly in CF, I'll leave it to the CF-Java dudes to say whether you can use a Java method directly on a CF var to achieve what you want, but...

You could use cfsavecontent to put natural line breaks in:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="someStr">
This is line 1
This is line 2
This is line 3
</cfsavecontent>
```

Then check it with:

```
<cfoutput>
<pre>#Trim(someStr)#</pre>
</cfoutput>
```

Note that the Trim() is there to get rid of the first and last line breaks if you don't want them.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering if something like this would work:

```
<cfset str = CreateObject("java", "java.lang.String").init("Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3")>

<cfoutput>
<pre>#str#</pre>
</cfoutput>
```

Alas no :O(

Comment: This feeds a CF string to .init(). And a CF string does not understand "\n". That's a kind of problem I like to refer to as "can-opener in a can". :-)

Answer (score 0):

CF8 formatted cfmail with line feeds and without adding anything.
Seems like Adobe would provide something SPECIFIC about "why" and a simple work-around.
... Jurisdictionary

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a way to output a new line in `<cfscript>`, so I figured I'd leave my answer for anyone else who arrived in a similar fashion:

```
writeDump(variable); // writeDump will not produce a new line.
writeOutput("<br>"); // you have to use writeOutput.
```

[`writeOutput`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-t-z/writeoutput.html) appends to the page-output stream as html, so you need to write html for it to output *(this means you can also include `&nbsp;` to add spaces for indentation)*.