# Coldfusion writeOutput code generation?

Tags: html, coldfusion

I am generating a website dynamically with a couple of ColdFusion functions, they use writeOutput() - the problems is that I get the code generated on one line only. So I get an error on that long line and I am not sure how to debug it. Is there a way to do a newline at certain points so that the source code generated is more readable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're dynamically writing Coldfusion code? That seems like a nightmare, and unless it's some cutting edge app, probably wholly unnecessary.

But, yes you could append newline chars. See this question: [How can I write a newline in a string in ColdFusion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987175/how-can-i-write-a-newline-in-a-string-in-coldfusion)

Comment: Thanks, that does work ! Well the website is a template for other ones, so I need to be able to change the content easily, pretty cutting edge I think. The CF code is static though.